# CULA - using Python solve() within CULA

Tags: python, cula

How can I incorporate Python's solve() in a Python CULA program?  I am using

```
LA = libculaC.solve()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "culaTest.py", line 96, in <module>
        LA = libculaC.solve(0)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
        func = self.__getitem__(name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
        func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    AttributeError: /usr/local/cula/lib64/libcula_lapack.so: undefined symbol:     
    solve
```

Any combination of liculaC and ctypes give me similar errors.  How can I bring this function in?  Do I need to use a C function (scanf) or something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This took awhile, but this is what I have so far.  Must use ctypes and must convert to column major vice the standard row major.  Use matrices not arrays and keep your data types consistent throughout.

```
import ctypes
from scipy import *
from scipy.linalg import *
import numpy as np
import sys
import csv
print     "___________________________________________________________________________________________________"

libculaC=ctypes.CDLL('libcula_lapack.so',mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
libculaC.culaGetStatusString.restype=ctypes.c_char_p

info=libculaC.culaInitialize()

#Row major-normal form, but must be converted-('4 1;2 5')
Anp = np.matrix('4.0 2.0;1.0 5.0') #Column major
print "This is Anp: "
print Anp
print '___________END Anp______________'

#use ctypes to convert from Py to C
#2x2 matrix
Anp = Anp.astype(numpy.float32)  #astype is array type for ctype
c_float_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)
A1_p = Anp.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)
# 2x1 matrix
B1 = np.matrix('5.0 ;7.0')
print "This is B1"
print B1
print '__________________B1 END______________________'
B1 = B1.astype(numpy.float32)
B1_p = B1.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)

X=np.empty([2])
X=X.astype(numpy.float32)
X_p =X.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)
print "This is X"
print X
print '__________________X END______________________'


info = 0
libculaC.culaSgesv(2,1,A1_p,2,X_p,B1_p,2)  #libculaC.culaSgesv

a = np.fromiter(B1_p, dtype=np.float32, count=2)
a = np.reshape(a,(-1,2))
print "The solution returning from Sgesv: "
print a
print "-----------------------Program End----------------------------"

libculaC.culaShutdown()
```

OUTPUT:
This is Anp:

[[ 4.  2.]
 [ 1.  5.]]

___________END Anp______________

This is B1

[[ 5.]
 [ 7.]]

__________________B1 END______________________

This is X

[ 5.  7.]

__________________X END______________________

The solution returning from Sgesv:

[[ 1.  1.]]

-----------------------Program End----------------------------